# Can not make ajax call in knockout

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, knockout.js, webmethod

I want help for making ajax request in knockout. Here is my js code where i make call to a webmethod.

```
 // Client-side routes    
Sammy(function () {
    this.get('#:day', function() {
        self.choosenDateId(this.params.day);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'SinglePageApp.aspx/GetData',
            data: "{goalDate:'" + this.params.days + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                debugger;
                self.choosenDateGoal(msg.d);

                alert("success");
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        })
    });
}).run();
```

And my html for binding data

```
 <tbody data-bind="foreach: GetData">
            <tr data-bind="click: $root.goToGoal">
                <td data-bind="text: status"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: data"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: notes"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

And in my webemthod i have passed day as parameter.But can not call to webmethod.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sammy(function () {
    this.get('#:day', function() {
        self.choosenDateId(this.params.day);
        $.get("SinglePageApp.aspx/GetData", { day: self.chosenDateId() }, self.choosenDateGoal);
    });
}).run();
```

I think the problem was the fact that you were using `this.params.day` within the `$.get` call. In that function, I believe `this` is a reference to the jQuery ajax XHR context, not the `Sammy` context.

Comment: But still its not going to SinglePageApp.aspx/GetData method.

Comment: Are you able to invoke the method without using jquery? For example, using a browser or Fiddler2? If you can't invoke it any other way, it may not be a problem with the javascript, it could be a problem with some other code that you have not posted in your question. Also, have you tried $.post instead of $.get? Have you tried $.ajax?

Comment: i have changed that $.ajax, so webmethod is called but can not get value in table.Here i have written 
<tbody data-bind="foreach: GetData"> i.e i have called the webmethod here and thats the problem. So i can not know how to solve the problem.

Comment: Please update your question with your ko viewmodel, including the GetData observable (or is it a computed)?